# What does (ttest\$conf.int[2] - ttest\$conf.int[1])/2 mean?

Tags: r, t-test

I am trying to understand a code provided by my teacher. He has done t-test and then has stored `(ttest$conf.int[2] - ttest$conf.int[1])/2` as a variable called "Confidence Interval Radius". What can this possibly mean? Observations for ttest are all accuracies from a predictor model (therefore all are in percentage)

Results are as follows:

```
Average accuracy = 41.23%
Conf level=99%  > CI Radius=5.87
Conf level=95%  > CI Radius=3.97    
Conf level=90%  > CI Radius=3.18
```

What can I conclude from such results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is half of the distance between the upper bound of the confidence interval and the lower bound of the confidence interval.

As the confidence interval of a standard t-test constitutes a circle in $\mathbb{R}^1$, with the estimated mean at its center, it can be described in geometric terms. So $UB - LB$ would be called the diameter and $(UB - LB) / 2$ the radius.

Here is a simple example.

```
set.seed(1234)
temp <- t.test(rnorm(50))
```

The t-test results in

```
temp

    One Sample t-test

data:  rnorm(50)
t = -3.6197, df = 49, p-value = 0.0006977
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.7045796 -0.2015264
sample estimates:
mean of x 
-0.453053
```

So the upper bound is -0.2015264 and the lower bound is -0.7045796. Now, we calculate the radius.

```
(temp$conf.int[2] - temp$conf.int[1]) / 2
[1] 0.2515266
(-0.2015264 + 0.7045796) / 2
[1] 0.2515266
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I completely understand this and how the radius is calculated. But I fail to understand what the number represents. For example in my case, you can see that the radius is 5.87 (at 99%), but what does that actually mean? How does 5.87 differ from another number? What if I had CI Radius equal to 1 or equal to 8, what are the differences? I cannot understand the meaning of CI Radius and how it differs if it's low and high. What can a low CI Radius or a high one indicate? Once again, thank you very much for your response.

Comment: The magnitude of the radius will typically vary from application to application, and comparing radii across applications is not fruitful generally. Within an application, the radius is a function of 3 things, the observed data (through the standard deviation), the sample size, and the confidence level ($\alpha$). In your example, you can see that as $\alpha$ increases, the radius shrinks. Given the same population, the radius will also shrink as the sample size increases. One way to "normalize" the radius for comparison across applications, I suppose, is to divide it by the estimated mean.

Comment: If we take the 99% confidence, my CI radius is 5.87. The average accuracy was 41.23%. Now if I come across an observation for which average accuracy is 48%, should I say that the observation does not lie in the confidence interval or it does?

Comment: 48% lies outside of the confidence interval, (41.23 - 5.87 = 35.36, 41.23 + 5.87 = 47.1). When you say " an observation for which average accuracy is 48%," do you mean that this comes from another experiment?

Comment: Yes, I mean this comes from using the same predictor on a different, unseen 'test' dataset.